# How to make javascript speechrecognition stop recording after a spoken word?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

Hey guys im using javascript Speechrecognition to convert speech to text. When I click on the button it calls the function to start recording here:

```
<button onClick={() => this.handleMic()}>Microphone</button>
```

This is the function `handleMic();`

```
handleMic = async () => {
            console.log("function 1 is called");
            var speech = true;
            const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;

            const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
            recognition.interimResults = true;

            const words = document.querySelector('.words');
            let p = document.createElement("p");
            words.appendChild(p);

            recognition.addEventListener('result', e => {

            const transcript = Array.from(e.results)
            .map(result => result[0])
            .map(result => result.transcript)
            .join('')
           
            this.state.searchedValue = transcript.slice(0, -1);
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = transcript;
            console.log(transcript);
            console.log(this.state.searchedValue);
            
            this.handlePress();    
            });

            if(speech == true){

                recognition.start();
                recognition.addEventListener('end', recognition.start);
                
            }
        }
```

So once I press the button the Mic keeps on recording even if I don't need it after speaking a word. Can anyone help me what to do in the code?

Comment: There are some other event you could try: [soundend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/soundend_event) and [speechend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition/speechend_event), which could give you an indication when a sound or word has been recognized. And then stop listening after the event fires.

Comment: try recognition.continuous = false; when is false it makes one recognition before result